# And odd command-line interface to parse arguments for

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I've got a command line interface for a Python program that has a bunch of options (say, `--a`, `--b`, `--c`) but one switches between commands with other switches.

So, perhaps `prog -S a b c` invokes the `-S` action, and `prog -Y a b c` invokes the `-Y` action.  `prog -Y a b c --a=2 --b=3`, then, should invoke the `-Y` action with parameters `a` and `b` and positional argument `a`, `b`, `c`

Is there any way to make `argparse` or `getopt` do the argument parsing for me?  Is there some other library to do this nicely?

Answer (score 3):

I think using argparse's [subcommands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) would be useful in this case.

Basically you can create a main parser that takes care of the parsing of the subcommand together with some common general options and then a few subparsers (one for each subcommand) that take care of the parsing of the specific options passed to the subcommands.

Comment: This is almost perfect... But it doesn't work if the name of the subcommand looks like an option.  It isn't actually ambiguous, since all options have two dashes and all subcommand names have one; but I don't see how to tell argparse this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this will help, but so far, I have been writing a wrapper that takes arguments from XML set by a web interface, and then passes them into the command:

Obviously takes more complicated argument strings, but for the sake of an example:

```
 def __main__():
 parser = optparse.OptionParser()
 parser.add_option( '-Q', '--ibmax', dest='ibmax', help='' )
 (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
 if options.ibmax != 'None' and int( options.ibmax ) >= 1:
                ibmax = '--bmax %s' % options.ibmax

 cmd1 = Popen([another.py, '-Q "%s"' % (options.ibmax),], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
 process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Depending on certain flags in my web interface, more options are added to the arg list and thus a different command is run. Add every command option to the parser and then check the value of the -Y or -S command to set vars and change which command you need to pass.

I hope this helps, I'm no python pro, this just works for me.